Cosmos DB query with array
We have looked at the docs and the only main thing we have found is the ARRAY_CONTAINS which does not address our problem as our issue is the inverse of this i.e. whether a string field contains elements of an array.
We are trying to create a query such that say a field called
Address has a value : "24 The Parkway, London W11AA".

We woud like to send in an array of strings as a query parameter such as:
["AA", "way", "Park", "24"]

We would like to make a query that if any/all of the elements of the array is in the Address field, return true else false.

Instead of passing in an array can you do SELECT  * FROM c WHERE RegexMatch(c.Address, "AA|way|Park|24")?

@MartinSmith Brilliant. That works for anyone of the elements being present. Any idea of how this can be done if we wanted to specify that ALL elements must be present.
Thanks you.

ARRAY_CONTAINS() isn't designed to search within a string; it's for finding a single element within an array. You could use regex (as shown already) or CONTAINS() to explicitly search for specific strings. Seems like it's going to be costly if doing a significant amount of string-searching, and might benefit from storing separate parts of the address as a separate property (maybe some type of "address tags" array?).

Try with this where condition RegexMatch(c.Address, "(?=.*AA)(?=.*way)(?=.*Park)(?=.*24)"). It might works because Address in this document contains all the substrings: "AA", "way", "Park", and "24".

@Balaji Well Done. Works perfect. Thank you so much and happy new year.
